# XSL-FO 2.0: Prevent page-break inside table

Tags: xslt, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I can't find a way to prevent a page break inside a table in the RTF output.

I've tried a lot of combinations of `keep-together` / `keep-with-next` but nothing worked for me. The actual version has a parent `fo:block` with the attribute `keep-together.within-page="always"` including the whole table.

**The problem only occurs when a RTF is generated.** The PDF is correct and no page break inside a table exists. The table has a header-row and 3 data-rows. In the RTF there is a page-break after the header-row and the first 2 data-rows. On the next page the header is repeated and the last data-row is generated.

It's very important that the tables don't include a page-break.

Here is the relevant XSLT-Stylesheet code:

```
<fo:block keep-together.within-page="always" > 
        <xsl:for-each select="block"> 
            <xsl:call-template name="drawData"></xsl:call-template> 
        </xsl:for-each> 
        <fo:table text-align="center"> 
            <xsl:for-each select="row[@type='declare'][1]/column"> 
                <fo:table-column column-number="position()" border-style="solid" border-color="#000000" border-width="0.5pt"> 
                    <xsl:attribute name="column-width"><xsl:value-of select="@width"/></xsl:attribute> 
                </fo:table-column> 
            </xsl:for-each> 
            <xsl:if test="row[@type='header']"> 
                <fo:table-header> 
                    <fo:table-row keep-together.within-page="2" background-color="#0000FF" color="#FFFFFF"> 
                        <xsl:for-each select="row[@type='header'][1]/column/block"> 
                            <fo:table-cell border-style="solid" border-color="#000000" border-width="0.5pt"> 
                                <xsl:attribute name="number-columns-spanned"> 
                                    <xsl:value-of select="count(../../../row[@type='declare']/column) div count(../../../row[@type='declare'])"/> 
                                </xsl:attribute> 
                                <xsl:call-template name="drawData"></xsl:call-template> 
                            </fo:table-cell> 
                        </xsl:for-each> 
                    </fo:table-row> 
                </fo:table-header>       
            </xsl:if> 
            <fo:table-body>
                <xsl:for-each select="row[not(@type='header')]"> 
                    <fo:table-row keep-together.within-page="2"> 
                        <xsl:for-each select="column/block"> 
                            <fo:table-cell border-style="solid" border-color="#000000" border-width="0.5pt"> 
                                <xsl:call-template name="drawData"></xsl:call-template> 
                            </fo:table-cell> 
                        </xsl:for-each> 
                    </fo:table-row> 
                </xsl:for-each>
            </fo:table-body> 
        </fo:table>
    </fo:block>
```

A screenshot of the relevant table: [image: Document View]

Comment: There is not really such a thing as "XSL-FO 2.0". Do you mean that you use Apache FOP 2.0?

Answer (score 2):

At the moment ([FOP version 2.1](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/2.1/output.html#rtf)), the RTF output has a few limitations compared to the PDF output; in particular, **it does not support keep properties**.

The linked page states that

> RTF output is currently unmaintained

and *keeps* are

> supported by the RTF library but not tied into the RTFHandler

so, while it is probably unlikely that this feature will be fixed in future versions without external help, it *could* be relatively easy to implement it (in which case it would be a good idea to [submit a patch](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/dev/index.html#patches)).